# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi}sin^nxdx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin^nxdx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Q:**

> Prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi}sin^nxdx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin^nxdx$

**My thoughts:**

First of all I don't really even intuitively understand how this can be true?Even if we take meaning of  integral as an area under the graph(which we yet didn't do) it is still unclear how area under $[0,2\pi]$ is equal to area under $[0,\pi]$.But anyway I tried to do some calculations.

Let $J_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}sin^nxdx$

Doing partial integration I get

$J_n = \frac{(n-1)J_{n-2}}{n}$

when $n$ is even I get $J_0$ = ${\pi}$

for $J_n=\int_{0}^{2\pi}sin^nxdx$ I get $J_0=2\pi$

Even analytically I don't get equality.

Please help with intuition understanding this and maybe analytically I did something wrong.Or maybe there is more easy way for proving?*emphasized text*

Comment: is n an integer?

Comment: @Vega Yes it is integer

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is incorrect. Note that
$\int_{0}^{2a}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{a}\left(f\left(x\right)+f\left(2a-x\right)\right)dx$. You have, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sin x\right)^{n}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\left(\sin x\right)^{n}+\sin\left(2\pi-x\right)^{n}\right)dx$. If n is odd you have the answer as $0$ else if n is even then you'll get a finite answer, that is, if n is even, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sin x\right)^{n}dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\sin x\right)^{n}dx$.
Kindly check your question again.

Comment: This question isn't from textbook my professor gave it during class maybe I understood question wrong. Then at what interval equality holds?

Comment: @unit1991 equality will never hold true. try to play around with the question on desmos.